# Color rotation/correction help request for GIMP

Tags: colors, gimp, image-processing

I'm new to GIMP and am looking for help on color rotation. Some target colors don't always seem to be accessible, or I don't understand how to get to it.

For example:
[image: Beige Example]
Here I can rotate the color from blue to a reasonable skin color.  Not great, but better than the starting image.

But here:
[image: No Beige Example]
I am unable to rotate to any beige color. The yellow/brown example is the closest I can get.  I'd like to target #fecd1d or around it.

Is this possible with color rotate?  Or should I be using something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [I removed your meta question, which isn't part of your actual question]. Yes, it's on topic here, but it may get better expertise on [Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com) or [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) You may need to split it into three separate questions, as each is a distinct problem. You'll also need to provide sample images.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the links.  I'm so new to this I'm struggling with just find out who can help and even what questions to ask.

Comment: See this for the blue shift - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/97629/how-do-i-correct-the-huge-blue-shift-in-these-images - for the rest we really do need to see examples. [Anything you can do in Photoshop usually has a Gimp equivalent.]